# Remove basic authentication header with apache mod proxy

Tags: apache, mod-proxy, basic-authentication

I have a HTTP Basic secured website. I hide a Tomcat application server with mod_proxy. Can I remove the HTTP Basic header? The Tomcat application reads the header and returns 401 not authorized. Basic auth isn't needed because the application uses cookie sessions. So I think just removing the headers would be fine.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Make sure mod_headers is enabled. An example config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName something.example.com
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost Off
        AllowEncodedSlashes On
        KeepAlive Off

        <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        <Location />
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Authorized Users Only"
                AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwd
                Require valid-user
        </Location>

        RequestHeader unset Authorization
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:5984/ example
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5984/

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/something.example.com-error_log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/something.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 16):

I just had the same problem with Apache in front of another Java server trying to do basic auth, adding the following to my Apache config seemed to fix it:

```
RequestHeader unset Authorization
```

Comment: Together with Proxy? Or what is the parent element?

Comment: thx. this was enough for me on apache 2.4 with weblogic connector.

Comment: I got here looking how to remove the headers on the response, rather than the request. For that, instead of `RequestHeader unset ...`, use `Header unset`. Also, with the optional `expr` parameter, you can unset the header based on some condition.