# Apache proxy to images on s3 bucket stopped working

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, amazon-s3, proxy

I'm using an s3 bucket to serve images for my wordpress site. Instead of having to change all the image urls to the s3 bucket, I set up a proxy from the main domain over to s3. I had this working before, but a couple weeks ago it suddenly stopped.

I set up s3 bucket to use a subdomain so I don't have the long ugly default s3 url.

Here is what I have in the .htaccess file

```
# Rewrite uploads folder to the s3 bucket
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/?wp-content/uploads(.*) http://content.site.com/wp-content/uploads$1 [P]
</IfModule>
#End S3 rewrite
```

Doing this it returns a 400 bad request with the following xml (Specific keys have been removed).

```
<Error>
<Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
<Message>Unsupported Authorization Type</Message>
<ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName>
<ArgumentValue>Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</ArgumentValue>
<RequestId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</RequestId>
<HostId>
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Any suggestions as to why the error is happening would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It looks as though your login credentials for the WordPress site are being proxied in the forward direction to S3.  Do the downloads work correctly if you visit one of the links while not logged in to the WordPress site (i.e. as an anonymous user)?  Does the bucket still respond as expected if you visit the S3 links directly?

Comment: Thanks for the response. It does seem like the proxy works fine when I visit the link in an incognito browser where i am not logged into wordpress.  Is there a fix or work around for this?

Comment: Now that you have a good candidate for the nature of the issue, see if you can find something from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428903/remove-basic-authentication-header-with-apache-mod-proxy